# Android Image in image view not showing up

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to take a picture with camera intent, save the image in sdcard,save file path in shared preferences on button click method and 
display the same image in another activity,but the image doesnot show up.

Here is my code

**taking pic layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove1"
            style="@style/SmallButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_remove" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/take1"
            style="@style/SmallButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_take" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**take pic code:**

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageName1 = "image"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"; 
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/new/images/"+     imageName1);
intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri1);
imageUri1 = Uri.fromFile(file)       
startActivityForResult(intent1, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras(); 
            Bitmap pic = (Bitmap)b.get("data");
            if (pic != null) {
                pictureHolder1.setImageBitmap(pic);
            }
        }
    }
}

onbtnclick()
{
    SharedPreferences image1Pref = getSharedPreferences("images",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor et=image1Pref.edit();
    et.putString("image1",imageName1);
    et.commit();
}
```

**anotheractivitylayout:**

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/pic1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

**activity code:**

```
SharedPreferences image1Pref = getSharedPreferences("images",MODE_PRIVATE);
String picName=image1Pref.getString("image1","");
File piFile1 =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/new/images/"+picName);

if(piFile1!=null)
{
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(piFile1.getAbsolutePath());
    pic1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
}
```

Comment: Try after removing this line in your xml file ::  `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

Comment: any crash or error report you are facing ?

Comment: Try to print out in your logcat that are you getting the correct path from the sharepreferences or not ? `Log.d("Path",picName);`

Comment: check your path by printing log like..Log.v("Path","Image Path is:--->"+piFile1.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: @AndroidLearner  that line was put because image view asks for a default image while creating

Comment: @UsmanKurd no error just image does not show up

Comment: @MehulRanpara,@grishu i tried doing that and it is showing the correct path

Comment: piFile1 have any extension like...png,jpg etc ?

Comment: i think you are missing those extenstion

Comment: and put your logcat..if there is any exception ?

Comment: @MehulRanpara no exception i logcat , file extension is png

Answer (score 0):

Just set the image as below:

> ```
>  if(piFile1!=null)
>   {
>       Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(piFile1.getPath()); <<<Change this line.
>       pic1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
>   }
> ```